# XSLT filtering nodes on conditional logic

Tags: xslt

I have an Source XML as follows:-

```
<StudentSet>
 <Student>
  <StudentName>Kapil</StudentName>
  <Subject>English</Subject>
  <Subject>History</Subject>
  <Subject>Mathematics</Subject>
  <Subject>Economics</Subject>
 </Student>
 <Student>
  <StudentName>Atul</StudentName>
  <Subject>English</Subject>
  <Subject>History</Subject>
  <Subject>Economics</Subject>
 </Student>
 <Student>
  <StudentName>Nisha</StudentName>
  <Subject>English</Subject>
  <Subject>History</Subject>
 </Student>
 <Student>
  <StudentName>Manish</StudentName>
 </Student>
</StudentSet>
```

The rules to be applied are as follows.

1) If a student has enrolled in mathematics, show student name and mathematics

2) If a student has enrolled in economics but not in mathematics, show student name and economics

3) If a student has neither enrolled in mathematics and economics, pick student name and any one subject.

4) If a student has not enrolled for any subject, don't pick the student.

I want to get following output:-

```
<StudentSet>
 <Student>
  <StudentName>Kapil</StudentName>
  <Subject>Mathematics</Subject>
 </Student>
 <Student>
  <StudentName>Atul</StudentName>
  <Subject>Economics</Subject>
 </Student>
 <Student>
  <StudentName>Nisha</StudentName>
  <Subject>English</Subject>
 </Student>
</StudentSet>
```

Can anybody please help what XSLT can be used for this?

Comment: Is this homework? This seems like a homework question to me.

Comment: You should post the XSLT code you already have...

Comment: I am newbie to XSLT. The one i was using was completely wrong. I was using variable and trying to change the value of variable in a for-each loop. After googling I found out that it is not possible to change values of variable in xslt. So that one isn't any good.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a better solution that allows to have the prioritized subjects passed as a parameter. Also, the transformation doesn't grow in complexity and number of templates as the list of prioritized subjects grows. :) You could also easily solve similar problems as: "Show the first two subjects from the prioritized list".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way is just use templates with predicates, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Student[Subject='Economics']">
  <!-- Handle economics students -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Student[Subject='Mathematics']">
  <!-- Handle maths students -->
  <!-- overrides maths+econ students, as it comes later -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Student[not(Subject='Economics') and not(Subject='Mathematics')]">
  <!-- Handle other students. Use 'Subject[1]' to refer to first subject -->
</xsl:template>

<!-- Handle students with no subject, outputting nothing. -->
<xsl:template match="Student[not(Subject)]" />
```

In each case, you probably want to do

```
<xsl:copy> <!-- copies the 'Student' element -->
  <xsl:copy-of select="StudentName" />
  <xsl:copy-of select="Subject[text()='subjectname']" />
  <!-- or -->
  <xsl:copy-of select="Subject[1]" /> <!-- first subject in list -->
</xsl:copy>
```

There's a shorter and more efficient way, but it's a bit harder to understand for a beginner:

```
<xsl:template match="Student[Subject='Mathematics']/Subject[not(text()='Mathematics')]" />
<xsl:template match="Student[Subject='Economics' and not(Subject='Mathematics')]/Subject[not(text()='Economics')]" />
<xsl:template match="Student[not(Subject='Economics') and not(Subject='Mathematics')]/Subject[position() != 1]" />
<xsl:template match="Student[not(Subject)]" />
```

What these do is describe elements that should not be output. For example, the first one finds any `Student` elements that have a subject of mathematics, and within that finds any `Subject` elements that do not have the text 'Mathematics'. The template matches these nodes, and outputs nothing. You could actually do this with one large template rule like this:

```
<xsl:template match="
  Student[Subject='Mathematics']/Subject[not(text()='Mathematics')]
| Student[Subject='Economics' and not(Subject='Mathematics')]/Subject[not(text()='Economics')]
| Student[not(Subject='Economics') and not(Subject='Mathematics')]/Subject[position() != 1]
| Student[not(Subject)]
  " />
```

Although it starts to get less readable doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a simpler solution that works with any number of prioritized subjects and uses only a single template of fixed size** It can easily be used for much more difficult problems as: "*Show only the first `k` subjects from the prioritized list of `N` subjects*":

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="vSubs" select="'x|Economics|Mathematics|'"/>

 <xsl:template match="Student[Subject]">
     <Student>
      <xsl:copy-of select="StudentName"/>

      <xsl:for-each select="Subject">
       <xsl:sort
         select="string-length(substring-before($vSubs,
                                                concat('|',.,'|')
                                                )
                             )"
       data-type="number" order="descending"/>
       <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
       </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </Student>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<StudentSet>
    <Student>
        <StudentName>Kapil</StudentName>
        <Subject>English</Subject>
        <Subject>History</Subject>
        <Subject>Mathematics</Subject>
        <Subject>Economics</Subject>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <StudentName>Atul</StudentName>
        <Subject>English</Subject>
        <Subject>History</Subject>
        <Subject>Economics</Subject>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <StudentName>Nisha</StudentName>
        <Subject>English</Subject>
        <Subject>History</Subject>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <StudentName>Manish</StudentName>
    </Student>
</StudentSet>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Student>
   <StudentName>Kapil</StudentName>
   <Subject>Mathematics</Subject>
</Student>
<Student>
   <StudentName>Atul</StudentName>
   <Subject>Economics</Subject>
</Student>
<Student>
   <StudentName>Nisha</StudentName>
   <Subject>English</Subject>
</Student>
```